# Send via SMTP using GSSAPI authentication with Python or Perl

Tags: python, smtp, gssapi

Our SMTP server supports the GSSAPI AUTH mechanism. I would like to write a script, preferably in Python 3 or Perl, that does an e-mail send to the SMTP server using GSSAPI. I can send using username and password with Python3's smtplib, but how do I do the same using GSSAPI authentication?